# Writing file to folder using Spring MVC difference between folder and file location

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I am currently trying to write an image to a folder using Spring MVC. When I'm trying to write to the folder I see no image. I think the problem is the write directory and the project location do not match. My project structure is as follows [image]

And my folder location is [image]

My controller for adding the code is

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/administrator/productInventory/addProduct", method =RequestMethod.POST)
public String addProductPost(@ModelAttribute("product")Product product, HttpServletRequest request){

    productDao.addProduct(product);

    MultipartFile productImage = product.getProductImage();
    //creates http path of the real path
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    //creates a dynamic path from the real path
    path = Paths.get(rootDirectory+product.getProductId()+".png");
    System.out.println(rootDirectory+product.getProductId()+".png");
    System.out.println(path);
    // if product Image is Empty it will transfer the file type to the new file type PNG
    if (productImage !=null && productImage.isEmpty()){

        try {
            productImage.transferTo(new File(path.toString())); 

        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Project saving failed",e);



        }
```

I can see from my console that the controller thinks the root directory

C:\Users\Trevor\workspace_jsp.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\HelloSpring3\

So my question again is how do I fix the mismatch between the controller location and the location I am trying to write to? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are using spring, you could use the `ClassPathResource` utility class

Comment: When you are running your app in eclipse it gets deployed to a tmp location. So when you use `getServletContext().getRealPath("\")` you get the path from the deployed location

Comment: How do I change the tmp location to match my images folder?